# Concat Dataframe to other DataFrame inside python function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, concatenation

```
 def fun(output_data):

        dic_ = dict.fromkeys(output_data.columns, "first")
        dic_.pop("col1")
        dic_.pop('col2')
        dic_.update({
            'col9': "sum",
            'col10': "sum",
            'col11': "sum",
            'col12': "sum",
        })

        tmp = output_data[output_data['col100'].eq('B2C')].groupby(
            ['col1', 'col2'], sort=False, as_index=False).agg(dic_)[list(output_data.columns)].reset_index(
            drop=True)

        output_data = pd.concat(
            [tmp,
             output_data[output_data['col100'].ne('B2C')]])
```

I have a data frame where I have to filter then group by and then aggregate on certain columns. But after concatenating I want to change the data frame coming as argument in the function. I tried to do this way but not getting the desired result.

**There is no option of `inplace=True` in `pd.concat()`**

Example:

Input DataFrame

```
col1    col2    col3 col4 col5 ...... col100
fixval  fixval  12   'a'   'b' ...... B2C 
fixval  fixval  12   'a'   'c' ...... B2C 
fixval  fixval  12   'a'   'b' ...... B2C 
fixval  fixval  12   'a'   'b' ...... B2C 
fixval  fixval  12   'b'   'a' ...... B2B
fixval  fixval  12   'b'   'a' ...... B2B
```

Output dataFrame

```
col1    col2    col3 col4 col5 ...... col100
fixval  fixval  36   'a'   'b' ...... B2C 
fixval  fixval  12   'a'   'c' ...... B2C 
fixval  fixval  12   'b'   'a' ...... B2B
fixval  fixval  12   'b'   'a' ...... B2B
```

Grouping done on col4 and col5 and filtering done on col100 where value = B2C.

Then I need to assign it back to original dataframe which is coming as argument to the function.

Comment: `concat` will return a new dataframe. You'd have to return it from `fun` and assign back. `return pd.concat....` then `output_data = fun(output_data)`

Comment: @HenryEcker Thanx for the suggestion. But this function is called dynamically so its not possible for me. Currently function can only return a series this is how it is implemented. And I need to change the dataframe inside the function.

Comment: There are no `inplace` `concat` `append` or `merge` operations in pandas. It seems more information about the constraints of this function/overall structure of the program would be beneficial to provide some options.

Comment: @HenryEcker Can't we implement it using .loc ?

Comment: Assuming that `tmp` and `output_data[output_data['col100'].ne('B2C')]]` don't have any shared indexes.

Comment: @HenryEcker tmp dataframe have col100 values equal to B2C whereas output data has col100 values equal to B2C, B2B and so on, so I have to put values of tmp into output data where values are equal to B2C.

Comment: Again more information about what is trying to be accomplished, what the undefined variables are, and the constraints would be helpful.

Comment: @HenryEcker Let me put some example.

Comment: @HenryEcker I have updated the question with some example. Please let me know if something more is required from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solution that I could find till now.

**It may not be the best solution but fulfills the need to update data frame inside function.**

```
output_data.drop(output_data.loc[output_data['col100'].eq('B2C')].index, inplace=True)

for idx, row in tmp.iterrows():
    output_data.loc[len(output_data)] = row
```